# return from onPreExecute AsyncTask without calling super

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Any one knows what impact of return from the onPreExecute in AsyncTask  without calling the super.onPreExecute();  Dose the doInBackground will be called
I have some conditions where I don't want the Thread to continue;

Comment: It is not mandatory that you have to call `super.onPreExecute()` and if you are calling `super.onPreExecute()` after that `doInBackground()` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will have no impact. You can check the code of AsyncTask [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)

and as you can see, onPreExecute is:

```
   /**
     * Runs on the UI thread before {@link #doInBackground}.
     *
     * @see #onPostExecute
     * @see #doInBackground
     */
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
```